# big query how to hide people's email address when we want to share dataset

Tags: dataset, google-bigquery

I have a big query project for multiple clients, they all have READER (and will ever only have READER) permission. When the client go to big query, they are able to go and click share dataset.

[share dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoBM7.jpg)

The client will not able to actually share it (when they click save changes, they will be prompt with an ERROR saying that they are not allowed).

However, they can see whoever has the access to the dataset, including other clients' email address.

Is there a way to "hide" other people's email address?

I was thinking to create a google group and add those clients to the group and assign the READER permission to the group. One thing that troubles me is that individual client can actually leave the group.

Is there any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups should works fine.
If you have g-suite - so google groups controlled by organization - you potentially can have audit on changes in group - so you can catch moment client leave the group. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members